# How to switch between activities on Android using the Java programming language?

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

I want to make a login program using Firebase authentication using an email and password. First, I created a register page with the class name "RegisterActivity." When the user successfully registers, the user will then be thrown to the login page. Everything was running smoothly until I wrote the following code in the LoginActivity class.

```
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            // Check whether there are users who have logged in or not logged out.
            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null){

                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                startActivity(intent);

                finish();
            }
        }
    };
```

After I apply the code above, when the user successfully registers on the register page, the user is automatically thrown to the home page instead of the login page again.

I know maybe I have to delete the code above, but if the code is deleted, then every time the user closes the application, the user will be asked to re-login. So, how do  solve this issue without removing the preceding code?

This is the code snippet in the RegisterActivity class.

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Register succces", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                            startActivity(intent);

                           
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Register failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Why user needs to come back to LoginActivity after registering? After registering they are logged in already and can proceed further to HomeActivity.

Comment: @Sergey I want the user to enter the login page first after successfully registering on the register page. Is that possible? If so, how?

Comment: I assume you are registering `mAuthListener` callback in `onCreate` method of `LoginActivity`. Try to register it in `onResume` and unregister in `onStop` of `LoginActivity` class.

Comment: I think that this article, [How to create a clean Firebase authentication using MVVM?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336) might help you understand the concept.

Comment: Thanks to all for the advice. I will try it.